# changing only thumb background color when a cell is selected

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have customised tableVew cells, each contains thumb and label. I would like to change thumb - only thumb - background color when a user selected it .. the user can select up to 4 cells then he has to deselect one of them to select a new one.

here i made the cell

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->     UITableViewCell {
    var cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("intrest") as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = InterstArr[indexPath.row]
    var img = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 3, width: 40 , height: 40))
    img.image = UIImage(named: "transparent.png")
    cell.indentationLevel = 1
    cell.indentationWidth = 45
    cell.addSubview(img)
    img.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
    var bgColorView = UIView()
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
    return cell
}
```

do i have to write the code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or do i need to make it in seperate function ?

Comment: Tell me if im being idiotic but, can't you just get the cell from cellForRow and then from there just change the background color of whatever you want inside the cell?

Comment: @Zil the thing is i want to change the thumb color only after the user clicks on the cell, also the user can select up to 4 .. not only one

Comment: The counter shouldnt be an issue, i can ex plain when i ll be at work and not on my phone. And i got confused when i wrote my comment, i meant didSelectRowAtIndex, not cellForRow. Îll wrote a complété answer in 15 minutes

Comment: @Zil thanks .. i already did some things on my code that i will edit above now .. waiting for ur advice

Comment: I finally added my answer, i hope it helps. I'm not the most reliable person since i'm still new to this, but I think my answer will provide a stable and working solution

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so here is what you want :

1. No highlight, but your custom changes (here, background color of an image)
2. Multi selection with a limit of 4. If more, no select allowed, the user has to de-select manually. (i kinda disagree with this behaviour, i'd rather have the earliest cell automatically deselect).

**Warning** : I don't know swift yet, i'm writing this in objective C but i'm sure you can work your way around that.

1. is easy : `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`  does the trick. You can still play with the cell but visually, nothing happens. (all the code is still exectued though)
2. You need an array or a dictionary (I would go for a dictionary because it's faster performance-wise) containing the indexes of already selected cells. Ask for help if you need some.

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, every time you select, first :
 - Check if the cell is already in your selection dictionary, if it is, deselect it and remove it from dictionary.
 - If not, check the count of your dictionary, if it's >=4, do nothing
 - If not, add the index to the dictionary, change the color, and execute any other code you need on selection.

Ask for clarifications if you need some, this is just logic, not code. But i think its a very good exercise to at least try by yourself for a while. (I actually have no idea of your level)

In your cellForRow method, you simply compare the current cell index with what's in your dictionary/array (ask for help if you need some), if it's found, simply change the color to red.

Unless i forgot something, that's pretty much it. It's quite lightweight in code & performance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the user to be able to click on four different cells and keep their state between the clicks, you could persist these in an array or dictionary. One way, depending on what the cell will contain, is to store the indexPath for all cells clicked (could do this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`), and then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you check if that indexPath is in the array or not, and depending on that change the cell accordingly.

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you also need to check that the cell clicked, isn't already in the array, and you also need to check how many objects exist in the array (since the limit of 4).

If I misunderstood the question please leave a comment!

Comment: i think there is an easier way to do that .. i can check the back ground color of the image itself, whether its red or not then write it in the array .. but the issue is how to change only image background - thumb background - when the user clicked on the cell ? @Viktor Nilsson

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but I guess you should subclass UITableViewCell at least. Maybe you can do the layout in Interface Builder and creating Outlets. Right now you could you reuse UITableViewCells and add more and more views ( cell.addSubview(img) ) to it even if it already has this added (If Im not mistaking). As I said, I'm not sure I understand exactly the problem with the background of the thumb, but I guess subclassing UITableViewCell, create outlets and set the background in cellForRowAtIndexPath could solve some problems, since you can easily access the views for cells.

Comment: And since you reuse cells, you should not depend on the values set on stuff for the cell, since the cell at indexPath A could be the same cell that is reused for cell at indexPath B.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can only change the backgroundColor of the thumbnail in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and keep selection style as None for the cell.